# How to put the content of same controller in same div

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

Please have a look on http://jsfiddle.net/ucerturohit/6L7jA/

In this fiddle, I have created two divs : one with `span3` name with `editor`. In this I have implemented an angularjs property.

what I need is that, the input box where I am typing should be in editor column i.e. in the left column and the output of this should be displayed in the div with id `intro`

How can I achieve this with angularjs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `ng-controller` to upper div which contains the *intro* div, and then you can put the `{{title}}` in the intro div. As long as the property is in the controller's scope, the controller will be able to do the data binding correctly.

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="Ctrl3">
    <div class="span3">Editor
        <div>
            <div>Title:
                <input ng-model="title">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="intro">
            <b>{{title}}</b>
        ...
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6L7jA/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: and can you please help me that if I want to enter html in input box and it should be implemented as html means <strong>Hello</strong> should be displayed as **Hello**

Comment: @lord_linus Then, just do `<b>{{title}}</b>`.